# Absolute extreme values of $F(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ on the interval $[-3,8]$

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Find the **absolute extreme values** of the function.

$F(x)=\sqrt[3]{x};     -3 \leq x \leq 8$

Hi everyone, I have a calc test tomorrow and I am still confused on this question. We have some study questions for the exam, and this question is one of them.

The answer key says the Minimum is at $x=0$ and Maximum  is at $x=8$. I found 0 as a critical point since $f '(0)$ does not exist, but shouldn't the absolute minimum be at $x=-3$, $y=\sqrt[3]{-3}$ since it is less than $y=\sqrt[3]{0}$ ? I don't understand how $x=0$ would even be a local min since the slope of $F(x)$ is always positive on the interval.

Was this a typo, or am I missing something about odd roots of negative numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.  To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs.  For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$.

Comment: 0 is not a critical point. f is increasing on that interval, hence your answer is correct.

Comment: Note that you are dealing with the **closed** interval $[0,8]$. For instance, take the function $f:x\mapsto x$ with $x\in[0,1]$. We can see that $f(1)\geq f(x)$ $\forall x$, but $f'(1)\neq 0$